# How to integrate RethinkDB into Angular 7 web app?

Tags: typescript, angular7, rethinkdb

I have a web application built with Angular 7. I have a table in RethinkDB that I need to subscribe to. I would like to dynamically change content on the page whenever the change is made in the DB. I do not need to publish anything from the DB, only read. I have googled documentation for this integration but could not find anything or any good starting point. If anyone has any good documentation or advice on where to start, much is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!